# How to setup Hessian Kit in iPhone existing projects

Tags: iphone

How can I set up Hessian Kit on existing iPhone project? What are the steps required to run a simple hello world program?

I have Hessian Kit (http://sourceforge.net/projects/hessiankit/) but don't know how I can include this in my existing project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I just download it and had a quick look. The download is the source code of the project.

1. Download and open the project in XCode.
2. Build the static library target.
3. Goto the project you want to include the kit in.
4. Add a group under the frameworks.
5. Add into the group, the static lib (*.a) and any header files (*.h) that just got built by #2.

Thats the quick summary :-)

Comment: thanks a lot, just one more question, how to declare @protocol for this (http://wiki.caucho.com/Hessian_-_Objective-C_2.0_Implementation)

Comment: I'll assume you are new to Objective C. A protocol is the equivalent of a Java interface. Simply create a header file (*.h) in your project and enter the @protocol there. Classes can implement the protocol and it's methods by declaring them in their header files:

    #import "myprotocol.h"

    @interface someclass : NSObject<MyProtocol>
    ...
    @end

Check the chapter in the Objective C manuals on Protocols and Categories.

Comment: A word of warning, GCC compiler have a bug that will result in exceptions for unknown selectors if compiled as a static library, without using the -ObjC linker flag. I suggest to always use HessianKit from source.